# How to execute function synchronously in Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 2 methods in jquery and i want to execute them synchronously, how do i achieve it.

Here how i tried but it got failed

```
Data.FetchData(function () {
    Results.Execute( $("form.form1, form#form2, form.form3"), false, checkresults);
    $(this).dialog('close');
});
```

Both of these methods are public and declared in some other file, Here i am able to execute fetchdata method but once its completed the second method is not at all running.

Fetch data method does not take any parameter

Comment: We need to know more about FetchData to answer this properly. You mentioned jquery. Is FetchData an async retrieval returning a jqXHR object?

Comment: its related to fetching some data, its not related to jquery, its simple method.

Comment: If FetchData is itself synchronous, and doesn't return until it's received its results, then you can just call one, then the other on the next line. But if FetchData is long-running and returns before it has its results, it needs to either emit an event, return a promise, or accept a callback. Did you write FetchData or is it coming out of a library?

Comment: i have written fetchdata method

Comment: How to emit event, can u post example

Comment: What is FetchData actually doing? Showing code would be best. Then we can give the right suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to name the result function and call it at the end of Data.FetchData function.

**Update**

Generaly, it would look something like this:

```
function execute(){
}

function read(){
// do something
execute();
}
```

Javascript (and jQuery) uses so called callbacks, methods/functions called at certain points of execution. I don't know how you are getting the data but it is by some internal jQuery function, then most likley there is success() function which is called after reading of the data is finished. Id you are going into JS only, you have to create one your own: in the reading function, just after the reading was completed call the execute function.

Comment: can you please post the syntax, it will be helpful.  i want FetchData to execute first then Execute.

Comment: no, u dont bother about data, like i want first FetchData to execute it resides in some other file and then second function Execute. i'm still confused